# Renaming Firebase event name in iOS still tracks old name

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

Recently, I renamed the firebase analytics event tracking names in few places in my iOS app. I did this totally in the code side.

However, post this change, I see some of the renamed events are not at all created on the firebase console. And then, for some of those which are created the count is registering as 0.

In fact, it appears that the events are still getting tracked in the older names as the count for the older events are increasing.

This does not seem to be the case for Android though where the count for renamed events is not 0.

What can be the issue here?

Also, while trying to do a debug session by enabling `-FIRDebugEnabled` flag in the project scheme, I am not able to see my iPhone on the Firebase Console's DebugView page.

I am able to see the following in Xcode logs though -

```
2022-03-22 22:35:32.766660+0530 My_App[302:6625] 7.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: app, EVENT_DELETE_PROFILE, {
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = HomeViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = 8100265676957722465;
}
2022-03-22 22:35:32.767119+0530 My_App[302:6625] 7.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled. Marking event as debug and real-time. Event name, parameters: EVENT_DELETE_PROFILE, {
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = HomeViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = 8100265676957722465;
}
2022-03-22 22:35:32.774844+0530 My_App[302:6172] 7.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: EVENT_DELETE_PROFILE, {
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = HomeViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = 8100265676957722465;
}
```

What can be the reason for the device not being visible in Firebase Console?

Comment: On firebase debug view some time there can be multiple phones being tracked so click the list on the top left corner and see if theres multiple phones, one of them could be the one your really using

Comment: At the time I was debugging, there were no other devices and hence it was showing 0 devices actually.